# Softlayer API: How to get Softlayer image's publisher

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Is there a way to get Softlayer image publisher's information instead of account id by imageid? I noticed the API: "https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/guestId/createArchiveTransaction" to capture image from an instance doesn't require publisher's information as post parameter. Does this mean Softlayer doesn't record publisher's information?

Answer (score 0):

A [SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Block_Device_Template_Group](https://softlayer.github.io/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Block_Device_Template_Group/) datatype has a local property related to the publisher (userRecordId in this case).

You can use the following rest API call to retrieve the userRecordId:

```
Method: GET

https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Block_Device_Template_Group/[imageId]/getObject
```

You will get a response like this:

```
    {
    "accountId": 12345,
    "createDate": "2018-11-05T10:04:11-04:00",
    "id": 123456,
    "name": "TEST",
    "note": "Only for testing",
    "parentId": null,
    "publicFlag": 0,
    "statusId": 1,
    "transactionId": null,
    "userRecordId": 1234567,
    "globalIdentifier": "globalId"
    }
```

Then, using the userRecordId retrieved, you can use the following rest API call to retrieve the  User information:

```
Method: GET

https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_User_Customer/[userRecordId]/getObject
```

Comment: I just checked, unfortunately the userRecordId returns our account information instead of the publisher's. That is not surprise since the publisher's information is not passed to Softlayer during capturing image.

Comment: yeah, there isn't any field or parameter to set a publisher, the userRecordId has the information of user who created the image through the createArchiveTransaction method